# Lax monoidal structure on the right Kan extension of a partially monoidal Γ-set

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, field-with-one-element, kan-extension

First some preliminaries. Let me write $Fin_\ast$ for the skeleton of the category of finite pointed sets and pointed maps between them on the objects $n_+=\{0,1,...,n\}$, where $0$ is the base point (equivalently, Segal's $\Gamma^{op}$). I'll write $Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}$ for the full subcategory spanned by the objects $0_+$, $1_+$ and $2_+$. If $Set_\ast$ is the category of all pointed sets and pointed maps between them then I'll write $\Gamma Set$ and $\Gamma_2Set$ for the categories of pointed functors $[Fin_\ast,Set_\ast]_\ast$ and $[Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}, Set_\ast]_\ast$ respectively (following Segal). I'll write $i\colon Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}\hookrightarrow Fin_\ast$ for the inclusion. This gives a restriction functor $i^\ast\colon\Gamma Set\to \Gamma_2Set$ which has a right adjoint $i_\ast\colon \Gamma_2 Set\to\Gamma Set$ given by right Kan extension.

Both $Fin_\ast$ and $Set_\ast$ have symmetric monoidal structures given by the smash product $n_+\wedge m_+=(nm)_+$, so the category $\Gamma Set$ has a symmetric monoidal structure from Day convolution whose algebras are the lax monoidal functors $X\colon Fin_\ast\to Set_\ast$. Suppose I have such a lax monoidal functor and I restrict it to $Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}$, obtaining $i^\ast X\colon Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}\to Fin_\ast$. Of course $Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}$ is not monoidal, so it doesn't make sense to ask if $i^\ast X$ is still lax monoidal. But $Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}$ still has a *partial symmetric monoidal structure* which on objects is given by $0_+\wedge n_+=0_+$ for all $n\leq 2$ and $1_+\wedge n_+=n_+$ for all $n\leq 2$. The product $2_+\wedge 2_+$ simply isn't defined (this can be formalized by either using this to define a [promonoidal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/promonoidal+category) structure on $Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}$ or by saying that $Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}$ is a pseudomonoid in the 2-category of categories with [partially defined functors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35784/profunctors-corresponding-to-partial-functors) between them).

With respect to this partial monoidal structure, $i^\ast X$ is still lax monoidal in the sense that there are maps $i^\ast X(n_+)\wedge i^\ast X(m_+)\to i_\ast X(n_+\wedge m_+)$ whenever $n_+\wedge m_+$ makes sense, and the various possible naturality squares commute, etc. I don't want to spell out every detail of this structure in this question but let's suppose we've worked out every piece of it, and say a 2-coskeletally lax monoidal (terrible name I'm sorry, open to suggestions) functor $Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}\to Set_\ast$ is  a functor equipped with this data satisfying all the coherences we're assuming we've written out.

**The thing I'm interested in is the lax monoidal structure (or lack of) on right Kan extensions of 2-coskeletally lax monoidal functors $X\colon Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}\to Set_\ast$.** There is one case in which I know that the right Kan extension of such a functor is indeed lax monoidal. Given a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) $R$ we can construct a functor $HR\colon Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}\to Set_\ast$ as follows. First set $HR(n_+)=R^n$ for each $n\leq 2$. The maps out of $HR(0_+)=0_+$ are the ones that pick out $0$ and $(0,0)$ in $R$ and $R\times R$ respectively. The inclusion maps $1_+\hookrightarrow 2_+$ go to the maps $r\mapsto (0,r)$ and $r\mapsto (r,0)$; the "conflate $1$ and $2$" map $2_+\to 1_+$ goes to the addition $R^2\to R$; the Segal maps $2_+\to 1_+$ go to projections, and so on. This is just a truncation of the usual special Segal $\Gamma$-set associated to the underlying additive commutative monoid of $R$.

The 2-coskeletal lax monoidality of $HR$ comes from, among other things, the fact that $R$ has a zero. For instance we need a map of pointed sets $HR(1_+)\wedge HR(1_+)=R\wedge R\to R=HR(1_+\wedge 1_+)$. This map is exactly the multiplication of $R$. Despite the multiplication being defined as a map $R\times R\to R$, we notice that $(r,0)$ and $(0,r)$ always go to $0$, so it factors through $R\wedge R$. The other map $HR(1_+)\wedge HR(2_+)=R\wedge (R\times R)\to R\times R=HR(1_+\wedge 2_+)=HR(2_+)$ comes from the action of $R$, by multiplication, on $R\times R\times R\to R$ and, again, the fact that $(0,(r,s))$ and $(r, (0,0)$ both always get mapped to $0$.

The right Kan extension of this functor $HR$ is just the "usual" $HR$, which takes $n_+\in Fin_\ast$ to $R^n$, and so is of course still lax monoidal (and extends the 2-coskeletal lax monoidal structure I just described). This might also work for the "inclusion" functor $Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}\hookrightarrow Fin_\ast\to Set_\ast$.

**The general question is then: under what conditions does the right Kan extension of a 2-coskeletally lax monoidal $\Gamma_2Set$ give a lax
monoidal functor $Fin_\ast\to Set_\ast$?**

**EDIT**

The following is a possible solution:

We have an adjunction $i^\ast\colon \Gamma Set\rightleftarrows\Gamma_2Set\colon i_\ast$. Both of these functor categories have monoidal structures coming from Day convolution (where for $\Gamma_2Set$ you need to use the promonoidal structure on $Fin_\ast^{\leq 2}$) and it seems likely to me that any 2-coskeletal lax monoidal functor is an algebra for the Day convolution structure on $\Gamma_2Set$. If we're lucky this will make $i^\ast$ into a strong monoidal functor (basically asking for restriction along a promonoidal functor to be strong monoidal). In particular that means that it's colax monoidal and so its right adjoint is lax monoidal, which would give the desired result.